# unable to catch org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException in jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

code in .jsp file.

```
boolean deleted = true;
try {
TestManager.deleteQuestion( ques);   
} catch(Exception del) {
deleted = false;
}
if (deleted) {
%>
<script language="javascript">
alert("The question has been deleted successfully.");        
 location.href = "edit_question.jsp" ;
 </script>        
 <% 
 return;
 } else {
 %>
 <script language="javascript">
 alert("The question could not be deleted.");        
 location.href = "edit_question.jsp" ;
 </script>        
 <%
 return;
 }
```

code in TestManager.java file.

```
public static void deleteQuestion(Question question) {

  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  session.delete(question);
}
```

deleteQuestion() method throwing exception but unable to catch.

getting exception as following.

```
[http-8080-Processor24] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot delete      or update a parent row: a foreign key const
raint fails (`test1/test_questions`, CONSTRAINT `TEST_QUESTIONS_IBFK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`QUESTION_ID`) REFERENCES `questions` (`ID`))

  [http-8080-Processor24] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener -     Could not synchronize database state with se
ssion
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at com.bhivesoft.phathive.web.servlet.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test1/test_questi
ons`, CONSTRAINT `TEST_QUESTIONS_IBFK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`QUESTION_ID`) REFERENCES `questions` (`ID`))
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 24 more
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at com.bhivesoft.phathive.web.servlet.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test1/test_questi
ons`, CONSTRAINT `TEST_QUESTIONS_IBFK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`QUESTION_ID`) REFERENCES `questions` (`ID`))
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 24 more
[http-8080-Processor24] DEBUG com.bhivesoft.phathive.web.servlet.HibernateSessionRequestFilter - Trying to rollback database trans
action after exception
[http-8080-Processor24] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/bhive].[jsp] - Servlet.service() for
 servlet jsp threw exception
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at com.bhivesoft.phathive.web.servlet.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test1/test_questi
ons`, CONSTRAINT `TEST_QUESTIONS_IBFK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`QUESTION_ID`) REFERENCES `questions` (`ID`))
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: I don't even see any question mark.

Comment: deleteQuestion() method is throwing exception , am unable catch that and page is redirecting to error page.

Comment: Perhaps you should ensure referential integrity, as the error message states?

Comment: what is referential integrity?

Comment: If you have foreign key constraints but don't know anything about referential integrity, you should learn database basics first!

Comment: i know there is problem with forign key in "test_question".But the prob  is try {
TestManager.deleteQuestion( ques);  //here exception is throwing  
} catch(Exception del) {
deleted = false;//am unable to come into catch block
}

Comment: You probably shouldn't be catching Hibernate Exceptions in your JSP anyway. (Google: Seperation of Concerns).

Comment: if i do so will it be a problem?